# QML - setting width and height has no effect

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

Quick Controls 2, Qt 5.10.

I created table control based on `ListView` item.

One of its columns is displayed using this component:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item
{
    id: root

    implicitHeight: item1.implicitHeight

    ColumnLayout
    {
        id: item1

        visible: !model.finished
        width: parent.width

        RowLayout
        {
            Label
            {
                text: "38%"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
            }

            Label
            {
                text: "Paused"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
            }
        }

        ProgressBar
        {
            from: 0; to: 100; value: 40
            // Variant A
            /*Layout.preferredWidth: 30
            Layout.preferredHeight: 10*/
            // Variant B
            width: 30
            height: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain me why Variant B does not "work". I may specify any width/height values or even just remove them - no effect. Variant A (Layout.preferredWidth/Layout.preferredHeight) works fine.

Variant A:

[image]

Variant B:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `...Layout` items alter the dimensions of their children. That is their purpose, and the behavior is documented.

As per documentation of the `ColumnLayout` [`Layout.preferredWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#preferredWidth-attached-prop) the behavior is:

> This property holds the preferred width of an item in a layout. If the preferred width is -1 it will be ignored, and the layout will use implicitWidth instead. The default is -1.

Since the default is -1, it will take the `implicitWidth` - it is not written "and use width instead".

---

If you don't want to use `Layout` don't use `Layout`. You can just take `Column` instead.

Comment: "behavior is documented." - can you please tell me where exactly? I do not see it...

Comment: Now I understand that changing width does not change implicitWidth. That makes sense then...